# How to set scroll height manually in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to make myself clear in this one

I'm making a web with several `<section>` placed in horizontal, full width, and their father has {overflow-x:hidden}. Then, a `<nav>` with buttons that changes the position of each section with jQuery. Simplified, something like this
:

```
<section style="width:100%;position:absolute;left:0"></section>
<section style="width:100%;position:absolute;left:100%"></section>
<section style="width:100%;position:absolute;left:200%"></section>
```

This is the premise. But, my actual project is a lot more complex, every section has different heights, and I found a huge problem in every browser I used except Chrome:

I don't know if it's okay to link my web, but it's a lot easier to explain: http://batxewebcomic.esy.es/ . Excuse me if this is not allowed :(

If you check in Chrome, everything works okay, once you change the section, the scroll automatically fits its content. But if you check in Firefox, you can see the scroll doesn't changes, and every section has a huge white content after the footer.

My question is if I can make the scrollbar as tall as the height of each section manually (only for Mozilla), so nobody can scroll over the white content. I tried lot of stuff and couldn't solve it, so I thought that could make it...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can solve this behaviour. I think the following two are most applicable for your use-case:

- Add `display: none` after the transition is over to the inactive sections.
- Add `max-height: 100vh` and `overflow: hidden` to inactive sections.

---

Having looked into your source however, I'd suggest you do away with absolutely positioning these altogether and use CSS/JS to get it working.

A simplistic snippet, is the following:

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function () {
  var chash = location.hash
  $('main section').removeClass('active')
  $(chash).addClass('active')
});
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.tabs li a {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<main>
  <section id="one" class="active">
    <h1>Uno</h1>
    <p>Insert content here.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="two">
    <h1>Dos</h1>
    <p>Insert content here..</p>
  </section>
  <section id="three">
    <h1>Tres</h1>
    <p>Insert content here...</p>
  </section>
</main>
```